# Not saving colon commands in MacVim

Tags: macvim

I am using `MacVim` on both work and home computers.  My colon commands are being saved in my home computers but not on my work computer.  My `.vimrc` on both computers is:

```
set shell=/bin/bash

execute pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin indent on

autocmd ColorScheme * hi StatusLine guifg=#268bd2
colorscheme solarized
```

There are slight differences in the versions.  Here's the working version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 31 2016 19:25:50)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-2196
Compiled by MacPorts
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+arabic          +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
+autocmd         +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+balloon_eval    -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+browse          +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
++builtin_terms  +fullscreen      -mzscheme        +textobjects
+byte_offset     +gettext         +netbeans_intg   +timers
+channel         -hangul_input    +num64           +title
+cindent         +iconv           +odbeditor       +toolbar
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +transparency
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
-cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
+file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static  
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/opt/local/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -I/opt/local/include -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -pipe -Os -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lm  -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework Cocoa
```

And the non-working version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jan  5 2017 07:18:47)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-94
Compiled by MacPorts
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+arabic          +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
+autocmd         +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+balloon_eval    -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+browse          +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
++builtin_terms  +fullscreen      -mzscheme        +textobjects
+byte_offset     +gettext         +netbeans_intg   +timers
+channel         -hangul_input    +num64           +title
+cindent         +iconv           +odbeditor       +toolbar
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +transparency
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
-cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
+file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static  
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/opt/local/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -I/opt/local/include -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -pipe -Os -arch x86_64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lm  -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework Cocoa    -L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -framework CoreFoundation -u _PyMac_Error /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my `.viminfo` file was owned by `root`.  Fixing the permissions on it solved this problem.